# iOS 13 : Space grouping separator changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, numberformatter

We use `NumberFormatter` class to format some amounts in the app. Since we migrated on iOS 13, it seems that the `groupingSeparator` **space** used for the Locale `fr_FR` changed.

We have tests on formatted strings amounts such as :

```
var amount = "1000"
XCTAssertEqual(amount.formattedValue, "1 000,00")
```

On **iOS < 13**, This test succeeds. But if we launch test on **iOS > 13**, this test will fail.

The reason is because the type of space used for the groupingSeparator property of `NumberFormatter` in iOS 13 has changed so 
`1 000,00` will not be equal to `1 000,00` according the space grouping separator which is used.

Any idea to always use the correct space grouping separator according the current iOS version ?

**Edit** : We found that the used space on iOS 13 is now the `NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE`

**Edit 2** : The `currencyGroupingSeparator` has also changed with the NNBSP, all currency grouping separator have been replaced with this new one.

Comment: Would it work to just set `currencyGroupingSeparator` to a regular space instead?

Answer (score 2):

Ok finally found a solution :

1. Defined an extension of `String` which replace all new spaces of the string by the original white space.

   ```
   public extension String {
       var originalWhiteSpaced: String {
               let narrowNonBreakingSpace = "\u{202F}"
               let nonBreakingSpace = "\u{00a0}"

           return self
               .replacingOccurrences(of: narrowNonBreakingSpace, with: " ")
               .replacingOccurrences(of: nonBreakingSpace, with: " ")
       }}
   ```

And use it in the tests :

```
func testIsFormattingOfAmountCurrencyCorrectWhenAmountIsNegative() {
    let actualResult = formatter.formatAmountCurrency(-123472).originalWhiteSpaced
    let expectedResult = "- 123 472,00 €"

    XCTAssertEqual(actualResult, expectedResult)
}
```

Comment: even i had faced this issue. if they keep modifying the separators in new versions of iOS, then we will have to add "replacingOccurrences" method every-time.